# recovering lost 15.04 GUI

Tags: unity, 15.04, gui

After the latest system update, I lost my GUI. how does one repair Ubuntu desktop/ Unity?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall Unity with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the `Grub menu.`

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `recovery mode`

Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.

Select:

The option `File system check`

and

The option `Drop to root shell prompt with networking`

In the terminal run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```